# Pyvirtualdisplay under wsl2 : pyvirtualdisplay.abstractdisplay.XStartTimeoutError: No reply from program Xvfb

Tags: wsl-2, pyvirtualdisplay

Here is the code I am using

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display    
virtual_display = Display(visible=0, size=(1400, 900))
virtual_display.start()
```

this results in

```
 XStartTimeoutError
No reply from program Xvfb. command:['Xvfb', '-br', '-nolisten', 'tcp', '-screen', '0', '1400x900x24', '-displayfd', '14']
  File "/home/vn/marl-interfere/render_mpe.py", line 134, in main
    virtual_display.start()
  File "/home/vn/marl-interfere/render_mpe.py", line 144, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
pyvirtualdisplay.abstractdisplay.XStartTimeoutError: No reply from program Xvfb. command:['Xvfb', '-br', '-nolisten', 'tcp', '-screen', '0', '1400x900x24', '-displayfd', '14']
```

xvfb seems to be running.

Comment: I have the exact same issue (timeout after 10 min), did you end up solving this ?

Comment: I gave up; thank you for posting your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me (windows 11, wsl ubuntu 20.04)

```
import os
os.environ['PYVIRTUALDISPLAY_DISPLAYFD'] = '0'

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1400, 900))
display.start()
```

from this issue
https://github.com/ponty/PyVirtualDisplay/issues/84